# How to set the input field with the value automatically from the database on the basis of other form field. using php?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to autofil the form field like name and address from the database, once they enter email in the same form. I am able to get the values from teh databse for that particular email, but not succeeding in putting that value in the 'name' and 'address' field. Following is the code sample :

**Index.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Email*</label>
   <input type="text" name="email" required/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <?php echo $model->Form->textBoxFor('name',['required'=>'required']); ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Address</label>
    <?php echo $model->Form->textBoxFor('address',['required'=>'required']); ?>
</div>
```

And in the same file my jQuery part is as follow:

```
$("input[name=email]" ).on( "focusout", function(){
    // Getting the email value
    var curr_email = $(this).val();
    // Making the request & passing the current email to the request.
    $.post( "/subscribe/getDetails", { email: curr_email}, function( data ) {
        // Updating the fields with their values.
        $("input[name='name']").val( data['name'] );
        $("input[name='address']").val( data['address'] );
    });
});
```

'getDetails' function is in **subscribeController.php**. The function is as follow:

```
public function getDetails(){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $result= [];
    $details = \Model\User::getList(['where'=>"email = '{$email}'"]);
    if($details){
        $result = ['name' => $details[0]->name, 'address' => $details[0]->address];
    } 
}
```

I successfully get the details in 'data', but not able to set that values in their respective input field. I know there is some thing that I wrote incorrectly in jQuery part where I am setting the values to that field. Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see you returning anything from your `getDetails()`. What is the format that jQuery is expecting? if it is JSON - add `echo json_encode($result)` to the final conditional (`if($details)`)

Also, show your form HTML, so it is clearer

Comment: @B-and-P Thanks for the answer. I tried with this before, but doesn't work. and I am just expecting the result to be in array. So I think I don't need to do this.

Comment: You say you get data returned so I assume there is controller code not shown that is outputting JSON, but shouldn't it be `data.address` and `data.name` in the jQuery? Also, not sure if its a problem but you don't need the inner quotes I don't think: `$("input[name=name]")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, you're getting the result in your controller, but not sending it out as a result.

Try this:

```
<?php
public function getDetails(){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $result= [];
    $details = \Model\User::getList(['where'=>"email = '{$email}'"]);
    if($details){
        $result = ['name' => $details[0]->name, 'address' => $details[0]->address];
        echo json_encode($result);  // this is the part you're missing
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggest, but still 'name' field and 'address' field doesn't set values

Comment: Okay it works now. Was doing some spelling errors. Thanks.